# Calling PHP file using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call a php file using the $.ajax() function in jQuery however it is not working. The following code is run when a button on the page is clicked:

```
if($error === false) {
        alert($error);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/new-user.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#name').val(),
                password: $('#name').val()
            }
        });
```

This is my form:

```
<form onClick="return false;" class="reg-form">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password-confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password-confirm" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn trans reg-btn">Sign Up</button>

    <div class="reg-msg">
        <span id="password-error-msg">Passwords do not match.</span>
    </div>

</form>
```

I have set the form's onClick to return false so that the form does not reload the page when submitted so that the jQuery can run.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does 'not working' mean?  Is the php script not being called?

Comment: Definitely `onClick="return false;"` should be removed. It's useless

Comment: Other than you're only sending the name entry in your php, what errors or issues are you having? What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: if your button that contains the click handler is inside your form, the onClick return false line could be conflicting

Comment: Wanting it to run the php file, if I remove the onlick return false, how do I stop the form from reloading the page?

Comment: return false in whatever event is handling the submit instead.

Comment: dont use a submit button and the form will not be submitted. it looks like you are collecting all the information in the ajax anyway. you technically dont even need a form for this approach. If you do need a form there is a nice jquery ajax form plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: since you are using jquery, consider using the ajax form plugin.  That will handle all that.  But if not, you dont want the onclick in there, you need to do your thing when the form is submitted - for ex, attach it to a click handler in the button, and there I believe you can return false to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: I am the only one who thinks is url should be  "../new-user.php" or "new-user.php"? does the "/" change anything??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main reason why people use **forms** is so that you can define an

**action** (in your case a php script),

**method** (GET or POST) and a

**submit** button that captures all the information in the form and automatically sends it to the server.

This is nice when you have 20-30 inputs or you are handling multiple file inputs. In your case you are handling the data retrieval in your ajax function, you have no submit button, action or method defined so you could make things a lot easier by not using a form at all....

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/new-user.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

I've left out the formatting divs for simplicity...

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus">
<input type="text" id="email" class="form-control">
<input type="password" id="password" class="form-control">
```

The above code will grab the data in your inputs, send it to the php script and output the data that is sent back from your php script in the alert.

And most importantly your page will NOT refresh!

Comment: Good point there @A.O. why use a form that dont do form stuff!!

Comment: It seems now I'm having a problem just trying any sort of AJAX request. For example: 

$('.reg-btn').click(function(){
$.post('new-user.php');
});

Does nothing at all. Should this not simply run 'new-user.php'?

Comment: calls the php file no problem, but no return is displayed.. strange.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
$(".reg-btn").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/new-user.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#name').val(),
            password: $('#name').val()
        },
        success:function(response){
           //Do something here...
        }
   });
});
```

Please note that you don't have a submit button on your form. So return false is of no use..

Comment: All that happens is that the page refreshes.

Comment: try adding the below code:
$(".reg-btn").click(function(e){
e. preventDefault();
...... Edited my code to reflect the same

Answer (score 1):

I actually serialize my form data because it's less code.  Plus you can use it with multiple forms.  For instance you can have a hidden input which holds a task number and have one php script to delegate tasks.  Or you can have another variable for the submit function to pass a your script's location.  Therefore I submit my forms like the following.

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm('#myForm'); return false;" id='myForm'>
     <input type='text' name='name'/>
     <input type='text' name='email'/>
     <input type='text' name='password'/>
     <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitForm(formId){
     var formData = $.(formId).serialize();

     $.ajax({
        url: '/script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success:function(response){
           alert(response);
       }
   });

}
```