# Execute jQuery function after clicking <button>

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, alert

I am struggling with the following piece:

```
<script>
$('button').click(function(){
alert("button clicked");
});
</script>

<button type="button" class="button-save">Save</button>
```

I do not get an alert when I click the button. I tried targeting the class with the button, but that didn't help either.
I am trying to execute some ajax (not in my example of course) when I click the Save button like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18539164/2976720) answer, so I need to find when the user clicked the button.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/8q7xd214/

Comment: See also the jQuery Wiki ... first commonly made mistakes

http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait until your page is completely rendered to bind handlers, else the elements dont exist yet. You have two options, move your `script` tags to after your HTML has been rendered:

```
<button type="button" class="button-save">Save</button>

<script>
    $('button').click(function(){
        alert("button clicked");
    });
</script>
```

Or wrap your code in a DOM ready statement.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function(){
            alert("button clicked");
        });
    });
</script>

<button type="button" class="button-save">Save</button>
```

Comment: @Bastiaan -- Open your console, do you see any errors?

Comment: You need to include jQuery then would be my guess.

Comment: @tymeJV, apparently I overlooked that I did not include jQuery ... My bad ... Since I just  php included by another I thought the jquery would 'transfer' too. Didn't think about it until you mentioned errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this line in the head section of your html page

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

and rewrite your code to:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(function(){
       alert("button clicked");
   });
});
```